# Is back-propagation outdated?

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

Back in the day in university (around 2011, 2012) I was introduced to back-propagation as the state-of-the-art in training feed-forward artificial neural networks.

In the examples to Tensorflow I have seen modern spins on gradient descent (e.g. RMSProp, Adam) being used to train all weights at once, but without using back-propagation.

From an intuitive perspective I understand that back-propagation is training each layer at a time thus having multiple spaces in which to optimise, but each with less dimensions (each weight of a layer is a dimension). In contrast, without back-propagation is optimising within a single high-dimensional space. Of course RMSProp etc. could be combined with back-propagation, but what I see is that it is not done.

Examples are https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros or https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/autoencoder.py

Is back-propagation outdated?

Comment: They are all using back-propagation. It's not a learning-algorithm, but a method to calculate the gradients where Adam and co. are used on. Maybe start reading [this](https://medium.com/@karpathy/yes-you-should-understand-backprop-e2f06eab496b#.ottq9vqi4).

Comment: @sascha: There is no back-propagation in the present code that I linked to: 1) The neural layers are explicitly programmed. The only place there could be something hiding would be the optimisation - which seems unlikely, because it doesn't even know I am training a ANN in the first place - but I went to see the code anyway, leading me to 2)...

Comment: 2) There is no back-propagation in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/rmsprop.py and the gradients are calculated from the total loss (not the layer's loss) in `def gradients` in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py. Thus: No, there is no back-propagation used. If I missed something, please point me directly to the explicit code. (Thanks for the article anyway - seems interesting.)

Comment: Nope. Read [this too](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d86cadcdf03ae6fef63f34c90150a4518a121de8/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.md). Excerpt: ```Because TensorFlow knows the entire graph of your computations, it can automatically use the backpropagation algorithm to efficiently determine how your variables affect the loss you ask it to minimize.``` + ```What TensorFlow actually does here, behind the scenes, is to add new operations to your graph which implement backpropagation and gradient descent.```

Comment: @sasche: Ok, granted, that is pretty impressive. Thanks for your answer. As far as I understand it would be possible to train a NN without backpropagation, would it not? (Even though it might be more efficient to use backpropagation.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's possible but i don't have much experience with TF, so i can't help you (most of my arguments are based on the assumption that the average TF-user will not want to implement backprop himself and without not much is working, in many cases). So take all my words with a graint of salt and maybe some expert will add his thoughts some day :-) (and sorry for the short and kindly aggressive *Nope* earlier; especially being a non-expert here)

Comment: @sascha: That's ok - I guess I was also being a little "confrontationalistic". I meant whether it is possible in theory - mathematics wise - not Tensorflow-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to [TensorFlow Autodiff](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff) and [GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape). Or [equivalent in Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html). It is using [reverse mode auto-differentiation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224140/step-by-step-example-of-reverse-mode-automatic-differentiation).

Before such technologies, we need to derive the Jacobian manually to implement the auto-differentiation (back-propagation). With the introduction of autodiff in TensorFlow 2.0, we can just run the forward path and the autodiff looks after the gradients (actually applying chain rules on the computation graph TF generates).

All we need to do is to surround the forward path with tf.GradientTape() and tell Tensorflow which variable to monitor. For instance, back-prop of  `y=x*x` was used to be coded as `dy/dx = 2x` but we do not have to anymore.

```
# From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape
x = tf.constant(3.0)
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
  g.watch(x)
  y = x * x
dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)
print(dy_dx)
```

However, there is a catch. We need to watch out and understand what we can use for the autodiff. For instance [Gradients do not exist for variables after tf.concat()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37726). Also the floating point size (float32 for TF) can cause numerical errors during the auto-diff process, and TF does not catch and tell us such situations, although it would be the same with doing it manually.